# NetLogo: How to make sure background image dimensions fit a world size?

Tags: netlogo

This might be really basic but is there a clear rule on how to choose world size or on the other hand image dimensions without having so many unclear patches with colors mixed with neighbor patches?

For example this is with world size : 32 * 32

[image]

This is for world size 60 * 60 Patch

[image]

And finally world size 70 * 60 which works best
[image]

Comment: Unclear pixels? Shadowy colors? Not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I think when we export view the dimensions are added by 10 for example if the world size is 60*60 the exported png file dimensions will be around 610 * 610 , so I need to adjust the world size other way around (if my image dimension is 600 * 600 I need a world size of 59 * 59 ) and that worked well in my example :)

Comment: Image dimensions for last example were 710 * 610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your math was off by one. Suppose `min-pxcor` and `min-pycor` are 0 and `max-pxcor` and `max-pycor` are 59. Then that's a 60x60 world, not a 59x59 world, because the patch coordinates range from 0 to 59, not 1 to 59.

Comment: ooops , why I did not think of that! Thanks for your answer :)